# Why doesn't this if statement execute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I am trying to make a word guessing game. Everything works except for the last if statement part. If the user guesses the name correctly, it doesn't print "Won!". However, if not, else statement executes and it does print "Lost!". Why is that? I checked it many times, but I coulnd't find any error.

Note: I use Python 3.6

```
    import random

def get_random_word():
    words = ["Ronnie", "Deskty", "Lorrie"]
    word = words[random.randint(0, len(words)-1)]
    return word

def show_word(word):
    for character in word:
        print(character, " ", end="")
    print("")

def get_guess():
    print("Enter a letter: ")
    return input()

def process_letter(letter, secret_word, blanked_word):
    result = False

    for i in range(0, len(secret_word)):
        if secret_word[i] == letter:
            result = True
            blanked_word[i] = letter

    return result

def print_strikes(number_of_strikes):
    for i in range(0, number_of_strikes):
        print("X ", end="")
    print("")

def play_word_game():
    strikes = 0
    max_strikes = 3
    playing = True

    word = get_random_word()
    blanked_word = list("_" * len(word))

    while playing:
        show_word(blanked_word)
        letter = get_guess()
        found = process_letter(letter, word, blanked_word)

        if not found:
            strikes += 1
            print_strikes(strikes)

        if strikes >= max_strikes:
            playing = False

        if not "_" in blanked_word:
            playıng = False


    if strikes >= max_strikes:
        print("Lost")
    else:
        print("Won")




print("Game started")
play_word_game()
print("Game over")
```

Comment: Well, print the value of `strikes` before the `if`...

Comment: Note: you can use [`random.choice(words)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) over `words[random.randint(0, len(words)-1)]` to get a random value from a list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at this piece of code:

```
    if not "_" in blanked_word:
        playıng = False
```

You have an `ı` ([U+0131 LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0131/index.htm)) in place of `i`. Python will happily create the variable `playıng` for you (unlike other languages where variables have to be declared). Therefore `playing` never gets updated to `False` in the winning case and the function never exits.

As Martijn points out in the comments, a linter may help by spotting misspelled variables and other likely errors. Consider using one in your editor or IDE. Two popular linters are [Pylint](https://www.pylint.org/) and [Flake8](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/).

Comment: Well spotted! Python 3's unicode name support really drives home the need to use a linter in your editor.